# Is there a way to ensure my cursor stays connected in my Python API script to MySQL

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python

Keep receiving the following error:

> raise errors.ProgrammingError("Cursor is not connected")
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected

The code I use executes as my database gets updated but on the second go it does not, what am I missing to fix this cursor problem.

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

@app.route('/api/v1/currentuser/updateusername', methods=['PUT'])
def api_update_username():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _username = _json['username']
        _user_id = _json['user_id']
        
        if _username and _user_id and request.method == 'PUT':
            sqlQuery = "UPDATE tblUser SET username=%s WHERE user_id=%s"
            bindData = (_username, _user_id,)
            mycursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            mydb.commit()
            response = jsonify('updated successfully!')
            response.status_code = 200
            return response
        else:
            return not_found()
    finally:
        mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line (outside the method) you create the cursor instance.
This makes your cursor available for the first request, but then you close it (and the db) at the end. So for the second request the cursor is no longer available.

One solution is to leave the database connection open and get for each request a new cursor (and close it afterwards).

```py
@app.route('/api/v1/currentuser/updateusername', methods=['PUT'])
def api_update_username():
    try:
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        _json = request.json
        _username = _json['username']
        _user_id = _json['user_id']
        
        if _username and _user_id and request.method == 'PUT':
            sqlQuery = "UPDATE tblUser SET username=%s WHERE user_id=%s"
            bindData = (_username, _user_id,)
            mycursor.execute(sqlQuery, bindData)
            mydb.commit()
            response = jsonify('updated successfully!')
            response.status_code = 200
            return response
        else:
            return not_found()
    finally:
        mycursor.close()
```