# Cursor not connected error on CRUD project using Python & MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

i'm just trying to use this code, but it returns to me that the cursor is not connected, what did i do wrong?
Thats the code (i'm a beginner, sorry):

```
conexao = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    database='bdyoutube',
)
cursor = conexao.cursor()

cursor.close()
conexao.close()

#CRUD
nome_produto = "todynho"
valor = 3
comando = f'INSERT INTO vendas (nome_produto, valor) VALUES ("{nome_produto}", {valor})'
cursor.execute(comando)
conexao.commit()
```

And thats the error:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Unknown error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****", line 25, in <module>
    cursor.execute(comando)
  File "*****", line 580, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError("Cursor is not connected") from err
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected
PS C:\Users\PC>
```

Comment: The error  occurs because you are trying to execute a SQL command using the cursor after you have already closed the cursor and the database connection. You can move this code `cursor.close()
conexao.close()` after this code `conexao.commit()`

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827519/is-there-a-way-to-ensure-my-cursor-stays-connected-in-my-python-api-script-to-my

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you terminate the connection using `.close()` methods before inserting your data.

Try executing your command **before** closing your cursor & connection.

```py
conexao = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    database='bdyoutube',
)
cursor = conexao.cursor()

#CRUD
nome_produto = "todynho"
valor = 3
comando = f'INSERT INTO vendas (nome_produto, valor) VALUES ("{nome_produto}", {valor})' # make sure table 'vendas' exists before inserting
cursor.execute(comando)
conexao.commit()


cursor.close() # this command closes your cursor
conexao.close() # this command closes your connection
```